# Intellisense not working with Jasmine on VS Code

Tags: jasmine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I really enjoy to work with VS Code and intellisense is great, but I can't seem to get it to work with Jasmine and its matches.

This is what im looking for:
[image: WebStorm Intellisense]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Jasmine in your node_modules locally, VS Code should pick it and provide intellisense automatically. Otherwise you can install just typings with `npm i @types/jasmine`.

Comment: Thank you. I do jasmine-core installed on node_modules locally, so I don't know why vs code would't pick it up. I will install the typings for jasmine then.

Comment: Even with the Jasmine types installed VSC's intellisense is not picking it up.  I'm using VSC 1.36.1 and have jasmine 2.6 and @types/jasmine 2.5.38.